# Apending data about image in to UL List jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list and for each **li** record I need to attach image, for this I have a function

The problem is, when I tap i to **add img** it's opening window and i upload image, then i get URL image and name, this url and name i should have in list.

In this moment the script is adding in-to list, but with duplicating previous values.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3f0qL6w/6/)

[image]

```js
$(document).on("click", ".attach-img", function() {
  $('#imgupload').click();
  $("input[type='file']").on('change', (event) => {
    value = event.target.files[0].name;
    console.log(event.target.files[0].name)

    var imageLink = `<a href="${window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])}" target="_blank">${value}</a>`
    $(this).parent().find(".file-name").append(imageLink)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Tets 1 <span class='attach-img'>add img</span>
    <p class='file-name'></p>
  </li>
  <input type='file' id='imgupload' class='hidden' style="display:none">

</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Tets 2 <span class='attach-img'>add img</span>
    <p class='file-name'></p>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Tets 3 <span class='attach-img'>add img</span>
    <p class='file-name'></p>
  </li>
  <input type='file' id='imgupload' class='hidden' style="display:none">
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Tets 4 <span class='attach-img'>add img</span>
    <p class='file-name'></p>
  </li>
  <input type='file' id='imgupload' class='hidden' style="display:none">
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Tets 5 <span class='attach-img'>add img</span>
    <p class='file-name'></p>
  </li>
  <input type='file' id='imgupload' class='hidden' style="display:none">
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Tets 6 <span class='attach-img'>add img</span>
<p class='file-name'></p></li>
  <input type='file' id='imgupload' class='hidden' style="display:none">
  
</ul>
```

Comment: first of all `id` should be unique for every dom element

Comment: You are using duplicate IDs `imgupload`. Which might cause problems. ANother thing is that you search for `.file-name`  but `file-name` for `test-6` is not in the same place as for the others.

Comment: @MihaiT this ```imgupload`` id i just use for opening window with chosing file

Comment: @GeorgeBailey all list item will be created dynamically

Comment: Yes. But in your HTML you have more than 1 `<input type='file'` with `id=imgupload` which is not correct and causes unwanted behavior in javascript ( among other problems )

Comment: @MihaiT maybe i can replace to class?

Comment: @Andrew `id` should always be unique each dom element. anyway, I've updated the fiddle. have a look

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong in here. 
First of all, [`id` should be unique for every element of the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page).

Secondly, all of the `html` elements that are being generated dynamically should follow the same html structure if you want to be able to access them using the same logic.

Moreover, here is the updated fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8akz0sh/1/)

Comment: _but with duplicating previous values._ is it ?

Comment: No, for now when i upload pictures, it's copie for each i row

Comment: are you testing the fiddle ? or just copying the `js` and replacing it with your js code ?

Comment: I test it, and then i copie js, in fiddle it's working

Comment: Nope, again some problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207166/discussion-between-george-bailey-and-andrew).